# How can i rewrite rule from link a to link b htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite

```
 http://localhost.com/cat1/test2/
```

to

```
 http://localhost.com/blog/cat/cat1/post/test2/
```

but I always get 404 error page. I rewrite index.php success but I can't rewrite link above

here is rule I write in .htaccess but it dont' work :

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/cat1/test2/$ blog/cat/cat1/post/test2/
```

How can i do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`cat1/test2/` and `blog/cat1/test2/` are not the same thing, which is a very good reason as to why it didn't work.

Use this rule instead:

```
RewriteRule ^cat1/test2/$ /blog/cat/cat1/post/test2/ [L]
```

However, if that was a typo, and you left out `blog`, then add `blog/` before `cat1/` at the beginning.